# Why I cannot import HeretoData from torch_geometric

Tags: pytorch-geometric

I got the exception when I want to import HeretoData from torch_geometric.
The version of relative components are:

- CUDA==11.0
- torch==1.7.1+cu110
- torch-geometric==2.2.0
- torch-scatter==2.0.7
- torch-sparse==0.6.17

The error was caused when I run the code:

```
from torch_geometric.data import HeteroData
```

And the original traceback information are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_discovery_two_layers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import load_multi, split_anchors, seed_everything, negative_sampling
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/GraphMatching/utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from torch_geometric.data import HeteroData
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch_geometric.data
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .data import Data
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/data.py", line 20, in <module>
    from torch_sparse import SparseTensor
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .storage import SparseStorage  # noqa
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/storage.py", line 22, in <module>
    class SparseStorage(object):
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 924, in script
    _compile_and_register_class(obj, _rcb, qualified_name)
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 64, in _compile_and_register_class
    torch._C._jit_script_class_compile(qualified_name, ast, defaults, rcb)
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py", line 661, in try_compile_fn
    return torch.jit.script(fn, _rcb=rcb)
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 940, in script
    qualified_name, ast, _rcb, get_default_args(obj)
RuntimeError: 
attribute lookup is not defined on python value of type 'type':
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/utils.py", line 21
    if not torch_sparse.typing.WITH_INDEX_SORT:  # pragma: no cover
        return inputs.sort()
    return pyg_lib.ops.index_sort(inputs, max_value)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
'index_sort' is being compiled since it was called from 'SparseStorage.__init__'
  File "/data1/gyc/PyG/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/storage.py", line 156
            if (idx[1:] < idx[:-1]).any():
                max_value = self._sparse_sizes[0] * self._sparse_sizes[1]
                _, perm = index_sort(idx[1:], max_value)
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
                self._row = self.row()[perm]
                self._col = self._col[perm]
```

I reinstall the torch-geometric and other relative libraries, but things didn't get better.

Comment: I found that it is not just caused on HeretoData, but on all the component in torch_geometric.data.